# Test for JavaScript Zombie event handlers or DOM elements

Tags: javascript, testing, backbone.js, single-page-application

In a recent project I have been working on (BackboneJS single page web app), I have encounted weird behavior probably due to [zombie handlers](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/) and some [stale element exception](http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html) (zombie DOM elements). I wonder if there is any way to easily detect any of these errors?

I prefer to develop on the NodeJS platform nowadays. So Mocha and ZombieJS for testing, Express/Mongoose/Backbone (if that matters)

---

**Update**

@DerickBailey: I am wondering if there are any automated tools that can be used to detect such problems? Currently, I only find them when I encounter problems. I am looking for something that can detect such problems, if possible without my interference, eg. if I need to write a test, I may miss something out. That is, if its possible

Comment: can you be more specific with your question, and provide a scenario that outlines the problems?

Comment: I'm sorry, Zombie Handlers? Why is this a popular framework again?

Comment: I see now... I don't know the anwser, unfortunately. I know Google chrome has some built in tools to look at memory usage and other things, but I don't know if any of it can be automated.

Comment: I suppose if thats the case, I just need to beaware of what I do then

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it, but came across this project from Google - [leak-finder-for-javascript](https://code.google.com/p/leak-finder-for-javascript/).

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The only real option I can think of is stashing addEventListener and removeEventListener into other properties of Window.prototype (I'm only assuming that's where all other add/removeEventListeners inherit from), then overriding the originals so you can attach IDs to event-bound elements for tracking what has or hasn't been removed yet and passing the eventListener arguments on to your alternates and passing args and firing your alternates after you do your id attaching/detaching/tracking voodoo.

I would not recommend leaving add and removeEventListener this way in production. Make it a part of some kind of debug mode.